# Objective-C - Works with strings, find a substring with NSRange

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, nsrange

I'm working with the strings and i have a little problem that i'm not understanding. In fact, i have a string like this: `"ALAsset - Type:Photo,` `URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=168BA548-9C81-4B08-B69C-B775E5DD9341&ext=JPG"` and i need to find the string between `"URLs:" and "?id="` . For doing this, i'm trying to create a new string using the `NSRange`. In this mode i give the first index and the last index that i need, but it seems not working.
Here there is my code:

```
NSString *description = [asset description];
NSRange first = [description rangeOfString:@"URLs:"];
NSRange second = [description rangeOfString:@"?id="];
NSString *path = [description substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(first.location, second.location)];
```

It return to me this kind of string: `"URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=168BA548-9C81-4B08-B69C-B775E5DD9341&ext=JPG"`. Is it correct? I'm expecting to obtain `"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG" string.`
Where i'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?
I have followed this url for help: `http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_String_Objects_in_Objective-C`

Thanks

Comment: Why are you reading sites like techtopia? All the info you need for working with NSString is available via apple.com. It has tons of great info showing how to work with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse the `ALAsset` description string! If the description ever changes your code breaks. Use the methods `ALAsset` and `NSURL` provide you. First, get the dictionary of URLs (mapped by asset type) through the `valueForProperty:` method. Then, for each URL, get the `absoluteString` and remove the query string from it. I got the string you were looking for by placing the following code in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method from the single-view iPhone app template.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
   [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
       NSDictionary *URLDictionary = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs];
       for (NSURL *URL in [URLDictionary allValues]) {
           NSString *URLString = [URL absoluteString];
           NSString *query = [URL query];
           if ([query length] > 0) {
               NSString *toRemove = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@",query];
               URLString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];
               NSLog(@"URLString = %@", URLString);
           }
       }
   }];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this range:
`NSMakeRange(first.location + first.length, second.location - (first.location + first.length))`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSRange first = [description rangeOfString:@"URLs:"];
```

gives you the position of the `U`, so you need to take `first.location+5` to get the start position of `assets-library`.

`NSRangeMake(loc,len)` takes a starting location `loc` and a *length*, so you need to use `second.location-first.location-5` to get the length you are looking for.

Adding it all up, replace the last line with:

```
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(first.location+5, second.location-first.location-5);
NSString *path = [description substringWithRange:r];
```